# Best strategy to locate elements on Google Translate by Selenium?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

Formerly the class names were meaningful kinda
`.tlid-open-source-language-list`,

but now there are only tons of random crap like `VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-e5LLRc-SxQuSe yHy1rc eT1oJ qiN4Vb KY3GZb szLmtb HotEze`.

So, does it force now to forget about CSS-selectors and just use XPath everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Classnames like...

```
VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe VfPpkd-Bz112c-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-e5LLRc-SxQuSe yHy1rc eT1oJ qiN4Vb KY3GZb szLmtb HotEze
```

...indicates that these *classnames* are generated runtime i.e. dynamically generated. They are bound to change each time you access the application afresh.

---

### Solution

In these cases you have to use dynamic and/or relative [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) leaving out the *Classnames*.